# R openxlsx Excel Export: XML Error

Tags: xml, r, excel, export

I have the following problem

I export data from R to Excel with the new library `openxlsx`. The code looks like this

```
mystyle = createStyle(fontName="Arial",fontSize=8,halign="right",wrapText=TRUE)
excel_export = function(wb,sheet,data,mystyle){
addWorksheet(wb,sheet,gridLines=FALSE)
#setRowHeights(wb,sheet,rows=1:nrow(data),heights=rep(0.13,nrow(data)))
addStyle(wb,sheet,mystyle,rows=1:nrow(data),cols=1:ncol(data),gridExpand=TRUE)
pageSetup(wb,sheet,orientation="landscape",scale=80,left=0.25,right=0.25,top=0.25,bottom=0.25)
writeDataTable(wb,sheet,data,xy=c(2,2),colNames=TRUE,rowNames=TRUE,tableStyle="TableStyleMedium9",withFilter=FALSE)
} 
excel_export(wb,"Statics",dg,mystyle,0.8,20)
```

When I do so, I get in Excel the following error message:

```
<removedPart>removed part: /xl/tables/table3.xml-Part with XML-Error. (Sheet) A attribute must not contain '<' enthalten. Row 1,
Column 133.</removedPart>
```

(I translated this error message from German into English).

I am using Excel 2010, 64 bit version and R 3.1.1. Language is set to German.

Answer (score 0):

I used to receive this error regularlly. I checked all my data/results in both R and Excel and noticed no missing data. I investigated a bit more on StackOverflow, Google, and IRC and the conclusion that I came to was that this message can be ignored.

Please inspect your source and destination data. You should be able to confirm that there is no missing data and if so then you can ignore the XML error.

Comment: Even without missing data it does not work. If I send data to more than 10 worksheets, the xlsx cannot be opened anymore. With less, all the formatting I have done in the data delivery is not reflected in the output file Could this behaviour be due to language or country settings? Or is there any other idea?